# Standalone Dynamic Form Editor + Serialization + Localization in C#

Tags: c#, forms, dynamic, editor, custom-controls

I'm facing a not-so-trivial problem.

I need an editor that will allow me to throw controls into a Host Control (e.g. a UserControl or a FlowLayoutPanel), similar to Visual Studio's WinForms designer.
I also need it to support localization, and serialization from/to XML.

The editor should contain a Drag & Drop style toolbox with a set of basic and custom controls.

The goal is to have a [relatively simple] editor that will allow a user to edit the Host Control on one end, then serialize -> transmit -> deserialize and display the result Host Control on the other end.

I'd be very happy to use a ready-made solution, containing a wide set of controls instead of me inventing [yet] another new wheel like:

```
<my_form>
    <my_label>text...</my_label>
    ... etc...
</my_form>
```

The editor can be written in .Net 4.0, but the result must be displayed using .Net 2.0 code (i.e. WinForms.. nothing I can do about it).

OK, it goes a bit deeper:

I need the editor to be embedded into a UserControl.
I have a predefined layout with several controls on it. I need to allow the user to edit the content of just one of these controls.

I already looked into Micorsoft's DesignHost sample: http://support.microsoft.com/?id=813808, however, I fall short on account of the Virtual Inheritance problem (i.e.: panels in a base Form/UserControl being locked during design-time in derived controls).

Any good idea on where to start? (I'll be happy to elaborate upon request)

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of these articles:

[Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1)

[Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23265/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-2)

[Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-3)

[Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4)

They might provide a good start of drag drop / resize designer - you could extend the objects to be more complex.  The later articles discuss XML serialisation and there are some features you can probably ignore such as paths and joining objects - but it might help to get you started.

Although the designer here is demonstrated in WPF, the displaying of the serialised XML can be done in Winforms as per your initial requirement.